# What kind of snails are these and how do I get rid of them

Tags: vegetables, pests, snails

I have a lot of very tiny snails in my large vegetable garden, and throughout the year they do a lot of damage to my vegetables. So far, products such as Bug-Getta do not seem to work (at least that is my impression, since after spreading it out I still see these guys and they continue to eat holes in the leaves of my vegetables).

Below you will see a picture of some of the samples I have collected. There's a dime there for size reference. The large one in the picture is the largest that I have seen so far. As a result, I do not believe that these are baby snails. I think they are all mature.

Any ideas for how I can control this pest? The "beer in a saucer" approach doesn't seem like a feasible tack.

For reference, I live just outside Houston, Texas. We garden all year long.

[image: A sample of snails from my garden]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are pretty common garden snails, not completely sure of species (I suspect *Theba sp.*). [Some people](https://www.gardeners.com/how-to/controlling-snails-in-the-garden/7309.html) have success with "barriers" such as surrounding the targeted plants with diatomaceous earth. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as well as the interesting link. That link also mentions diatomaceous earth, which I am pondering. I have used it in the past. Maybe I need to try again. I am going to wait a bit before I choose a "correct answer."

Answer (score 3):

If a grainy bait like Bug-Getta is not working, you may not be using it to the best advantage.

It must be spread **thinly**, it must draw the snails **away** from the plant, and it is best placed between the dining room (your plants) and the bedroom (**some wet place** on the north side where peppermint grows) where they sleep at night.

No harm in also spraying leaves they like with soapy water, especially the undersides. Weekly.

Comment: Interesting comment. I have been spreading the Beg-Getta near the plans, as I though that might encourage the snails to eat it instead of my leaves. Thank you for taking the time. I am going to try the suggestions that have been offered.